# Install codec for mkv

Tags: codec, audience

I would really like to take use of Audience. But most of the movies I got on my PC are .mkv files. Is there a way to install the codec I need to play them in Audience? I'm not a great fan of the audio quality in VLC which I'm currently using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Audience** is a gstreamer based video player, so you can reproduced matroska video files with it. To do this you must make sure you have installed enconding/decoding GStreamer libraries. Open a terminal and execute:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep gstreamer1.0-libav
dpkg --get-selections | grep libavformat54
```

When execute them, you can see an output indicating they are installed, like this:

[image]

If you want to play multiple formats, i should recommend you to install Ubuntu-restricted-extras package. In terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```